Using XOR operation, a MOD operation compute a function f(n)
I had a difficult assignment in my Data Structures and Algorithms class.
We need to implement a program that computes a function f(n) based on the following known values of n and f(n):
n     : 9689  9941  11213  19937  21701  23209  44497  86243  110503  132049
f(n)  : 3     5     7      13     17     19     23     37     47      59
n     : 216091  756839  859433  1257787  1398269  2976221  3021377
f(n)  : 61      67      71      79       89       101      103
The requirements of the assignment are as follows：

We are allowed to use a pre-initialized array with 17 numbers.
We can use one XOR operation and one MOD operation.
We can access the array in a read-only manner.
The program should not crash if an input n is not listed. The output can be arbitrary in such cases.

Another requirement may be to minimize operations and memory usage.
The first thing I want to know is what knowledge I should apply to this problem. I have currently written a program that stores f(n) in an array and when we enter n, takes the remainder of each input n and each number in the array. I printed out the results to try to be able to get some insight. But I wasn't. My other thought is that maybe this question has something to do with hashing, but I don't have a clue. My biggest doubt is how should we use XOR in the question.
I am open to suggestions and alternative approaches. Thank you in advance!

Does or doesn't a pre-initialized array with 17 numbers mean an array of size 17? The task may be simpler with a 23-element array, trivial with a 3020100 element one.

In the task is what I wrote above. My understanding is that it can be thought of as an Array of size 17

If you look at the seventeen function values provided, they all share a particular mathematical property. Coincidence? I think not.

As we want to use both operations, we only have two possible combinations:
$$\left(n \oplus x\right) \mod s\tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\left(n \mod x\right) \oplus s\tag{2}$$
If we store $f\left(n\right)$ in an array $a$ of length $17$, we want our index $i$ to lie within the interval $\left[0,16\right]$. We can achieve this by choosing $\eqref{1}$ with $s = 17$.
Now we need to find $x \;\forall\; n : a\left[\left(n\oplus x\right) \mod 17\right]=f\left(n\right)$
Considering that we can store our elements $f\left(n\right)$ in $a$ in any order, this problem can be brute forced quite easily.
